# Survey 'overlay' functionality for campaigns

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, survey

I am looking for the overlay that comes down from the top of the screen and lets people either go to the survey or select “no thanks.” What kind of flexibility do we have with this functionality? Can we put any content we like in that space (i.e., text and images)?

Comment: This question is not really clear. For example do you mean technically or conceptually?

Comment: I meant technically. It will be great help if you can point me to some sample code like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can put anything in there.

Conceptually it is a bit different for me:
You see this mostly used to softly point a user to something, with as less disturbance as possible. As such it is clear that the more content you put in it, the more you defy it's purpose.

So in short:
if you want to show the user something that he might like or that you want him to do but that is not really needed, without disturbing the normal flow of the user, use such an overlay.

If there is something that the user really has to know about / has to do, then you should consider other options (for example a modal dialog).

In every case you should consider the importance of the message versus the impact on usability.